# Design Toggle Button with On and Off State in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android, android-chips

I want to design a button like that (it's a kind of toggle button with on and off); any suggestion or ready library or view to use it directly?

[image]

Comment: You can subclass MaterialButton, which supports checked states, and override the `toggle` function to show and hide the icon based on `isChecked`. Use a state list drawable for the button tint and text color that has different colors for the checked states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`Chip`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md#choice-chip).
Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
      android:id="@+id/some_chip"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:checked="true"
      android:text="Text 1" />
```

[image]